# Unable to proceed Windows installation on Mac

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, windows

I'm trying to install Windows on my Mac. I got 2017 Macbook Pro (2 thunderbolt 3 ports), A1708.

I have prepared my bootable drive (Windows 10, 1903). I am able to select a boot option (pressing option key on startup, and selecting EFI boot).

Upon entering the Windows installation, it shows the language selection screen as start of installation. However, built-in keyboard and mouse are not working so I can't proceed. Tried the same bootable drive on Macbook Air, and keyboard/mouse seems to be working fine.

Anyone experienced this problem? Hope you got suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing a dual boot? have you got two partitions or more?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing a dual boot. I created a partition via Disk Utility before installing, ExFAT with MBR.

Comment: You cannot install Windows on ExFAT, even on a PC; & how did you persuade Disk Utility to make a protected MBR? You need Boot Camp to do that.

Comment: I managed to get keyboard/mouse working, seems I'm using the wrong Windows support software. Although the problem now is the when Windows installation restarts, it only restarts to black screen.


@Tetsujin, I just used ExFAT for the partition. But on installation, I let the Windows installer format it again.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get this working.

For the keyboard/mouse issue, this is related to the Windows support software download from Boot Camp. Boot Camp Assistant > Action > Download Windows Support Software. Mine was around 1GB. Be patient. Don't use direct links you might find from other posts linking you to Apple support downloads. The contents should be copied inside your bootable drive.

As for the black screen restart that I encountered, that was my fault. I was using a Windows 7 ISO instead of the Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft downloads.

Managed to complete installation. Able to boot to Windows no problem. Will just have to test if there are things which are not working.

By the way, I only went this route because Boot Camp is giving me issues and I had to retry a lot on Boot Camp. Would be good if they somehow cache the downloaded support software.